# Jhipster registry does not allow Eureka Endpoints for sidecar registration

Tags: jhipster, netflix-eureka, jhipster-registry

How do I connect to Jhipster registry using Eureka endpoints?
I followed [this blog](http://stytex.de/blog/2016/01/18/spring-cloud-sidecar-applications/).

But Jhipster registry doesn't to recognise sidecar and the registration fails with

> 404 Bad request.

Comment: What are you using for your eureka URL?

Comment: I want to register the sidecar application using 
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${eureka-url:http://localhost:8761/eureka/}
Firstly, http://localhost:8761/eureka/ is not available in jhipster
I tried replacing the defaultZone with jhipster registry url (with password) but no luck

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was to frame the defaultZone using jhipster username and password  http://admin:admin@localhost:8761/eureka/
The 404 error is because of jhipster security for any request coming on /eureka/**